# If one of the Dini derivatives is bounded, then f is Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives

> If one of its Dini derivatives (say $D^+$) is bounded show that a function $f$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition,
>
> Definition of the upper right Dini derivative: $$D^{+}f(x) =
>  \limsup_{h\to\ 0^+} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$

This is a question appearing in Royden's *Real Analysis* textbook. (Edition 3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I knew somebody would find a reason to distrust Royden--his text has survived way too long and none of us later textbook writers have been able to knock it out.

Take the function $f(x)=x$ for $-\infty < x < 0$ and $f(x)=1+x$ for $0\leq x < \infty$.  Then $D^+f(x) =1 $ at every point but no Lipschitz condition and not even continuous.

The result that Royden was going for was a theorem of Dini's from 1878.

> U. Dini, *Fondamenti per la teoretica delle funzione di variabli
>   reali*, Pisa 1878.

But Dini assumed that $f$ is *continuous*!

There is a full account in S. Saks, *Theory of the Integral* (1937) p.~204.

P.S. Royden's first edition was from 1963.  The third edition, which is the only one I have, is from 1988 and the mistake survives in that edition.  Does anyone have a later edition where the problem was corrected?

Comment: From the fourth edition: Show that a continuous function $f$ on $[a,b]$ is Lipschitz if its upper and lower derivatives are bounded on $(a,b)$.

Comment: @user0  Curious!  Why did the question get downgraded from "one of the Dini derivatives" to both "upper and lower derivatives?"  Also please excuse the dig at Royden--it was just a joke.

Comment: Is the following problem solvable, and if so, how? Show that a continuous function *f* on [*a*,*b*] is Lipschitz if its upper derivative is bounded on (*a*,*b*).

Comment: @user0  An accessible reference is R. Chalkley, Bounds for difference quotients and derivates. Amer. Math. Monthly 82 (1975), 277–279.  I did have to find (in Italian) the exact page for the Dini reference but, even though it is on-line, perhaps you won't want that.  Also, as I said above "There is a full account in S. Saks, Theory of the Integral (1937) p. 204."